# I have problems with using IQueryable<T>

Tags: c#, interface, iqueryable

I have problems with IQueryable. What I want to do is write library that allows access to database. But first - in my database there are 3 tables - drivers, cars, tracks. And now how to make a class (or classes) that implements IQueryable and allows lazy loading. I don't want to access like get all rows to list and that filter. Should I write 3 model classes and implement IQueryable within each class or write 3 model classes and another class (classes?) implementing IQueryable? I was looking for some tutorials but almost every site is telling about differences between IQueryable and IEnumerable. I am a bit confused right now. Could anyone give me some guide how to implement this interface correctly?

Thank in advance to any answer.

Comment: How are you accessing the DB?

Comment: IQueryable is a collection class (which extends IEnumerable). Your classes don't implement it, they use that for various collections in your class that you want to be loaded lazily.

Comment: I think I could access through SqlConnection and SqlCommands. But I don't know the best way of accessing data.

Comment: Don't write your own data access layer/ORM. NHibernate and the like are your friend

Comment: @IronMan84 so how I should implement getting data from one table? By LINQ to SQL? I have a little problem of imagine how it should be implemented...

Comment: @Jedediah i know that there are EntityFramework or nHibernate. But I want to be able to write something on my own :)

Answer (score 1):

Writing your own library that provides a `IQueryable` that does not rely on [linq to objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397919.aspx) (which is just wrapping a `IEnumerable` inside `IQueryable`)
is very difficult and not simple at all. You will not find any simple tutorials on this subject as it is too complex of a topic to cover in a simple single tutorial.

If you still want to do it and still want a "tutorial", the first place is to start here: "[LINQ: Building an IQueryable Provider - Part I](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattwar/archive/2007/07/30/linq-building-an-iqueryable-provider-part-i.aspx)" (there are 17 parts to the series). Once you have the ability to parse out IQueryable requests you then can connect that to whatever database interface you want to use.

I highly recommend that you let someone else do the work for you and just use a pre-made [ORM library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-relational_mapping_software#.NET) instead.

Comment: First of all thanks for the link. And second it seems to be more complicated than i thought. But still worth trying to get through :) For my own I still want to get it to work. Anyway than for your answer.